# TypeError: Failed to Fetch using sails

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I am aware the CORS policy. I am new to SAILS.js.
I have set

```
 cors: {
    allRoutes: true,
    allowOrigins: '*',
    allowCredentials: false,
  },
```

in the Security.js. From my React UI I am making a request to the Backend

```
let options = {
                url: 'http://localhost:1337/api/signup',
                method: 'POST',
                body: body,
                json: true
            }
            request(options, (err, res, body) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    reject(err);
                }
                resolve(body);
            });
```

In my Action code I am setting the header to allow cors.
The issue is still with CORS only as when I am using Postman with Valid Parameters I am getting the response.
I have tried all the solution in other similar questions but its sort of unsolvable by me.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header. It must come from the server in response to a cross-origin request. **Do not add it to your request**

Comment: I added that. Now the records are being saved but, I am still not getting the response in the Frontend.

Comment: Your headers don't make sense in your request. Remove headers altogether from your request and try again. If you need to set headers you will also have to allow those headers on server-side. For example, in your cors object you can add something like `allowRequestHeaders : 'Content-Type, Authorization' `.

Comment: Ok, But I dont think that will still solve the issue I have.
All the request I make from the frontend are giving failed to fetch.

Comment: What is the actual error message? Check your browser's _Network_ console for details about the request and response. Take screenshots and add them to your question so we can help